# Сохранение последнего использованного пути QFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qfiledialog, closeevent

Есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
def btnDataClicked(self):
    fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
    self.dataEdit.setText(fname)
```

Затем этот путь будет использоваться внутри кода.

**Как выглядит опция открывания/сохранения последнего открытого пути?**

---

То, что внутри сессии открывается последний открытый путь известно, **но что делать, если программу закроют и снова откроют**, и при этом, желательно чтобы путь сохранился?

Comment: `self.dataEdit.text()`

Comment: Сохраняем в конфиг последний путь и при повторном запуске считываем его. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я еще раз прочитал ваш вопрос и увидел решение вашей задачи так:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.is_saved = True 
        # для сохранения  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv последнего использованного пути QFileDialog
        self.file_name = "saved_file_path.txt" 

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)                             
        self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_textchanged_func)

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.buttonSave = QPushButton('Save file_path', self)         
        self.buttonSave.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_save)
        self.buttonNew = QPushButton('New file_path', self)         
        self.buttonNew.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 6, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 7, 0, 1, 2 )
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonSave, 8, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonNew, 8, 1)

        self.check_file_existence()

    def check_file_existence(self):
        self.file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)
        if not os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
            self.buttonSave.setEnabled(False)
            return

        with open(self.file_path, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()            
        self.label.setText(text)

        if not text:
            self.buttonSave.setEnabled(False)
            return
        with open(text, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()         
        self.textEdit.setText(text) 

    def btnDataClicked(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                                            self, 
                                            "Select file", 
                                            "", 
                                            "Files (*.py *.txt)"
                                           )[0]   
        if not fname:
            self.buttonSave.setEnabled(False)
            return
        self.buttonSave.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setText(fname) 
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()          
        self.textEdit.setText(text)        

    def on_textchanged_func(self):                      
        if self.textEdit.toPlainText(): 
            self.is_saved = False
        else:
            self.is_saved = True

    def on_clicked_save(self):
        self.save_func(self.label.text())
        self.is_saved = True

    def save_func(self, text): 
        self.file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)
        with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):                   
        if not self.is_saved:
            choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 
                                          '', 
                                          'Вы хотите сохранить последний использованный путь QFileDialog?',
                                          QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.save_func(self.label.text())
                QCloseEvent.accept()
            elif choice == QMessageBox.No:
                QCloseEvent.accept()
            else:
                QCloseEvent.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]